# Object not showing the value

Tags: php

I have the following type of object :

```
[RateInfo] => stdClass Object
                            (
                               [@rateChange] => false
                               [@promo] => false
                               [@priceBreakdown] => true
                            )
```

When I am trying to print the array in php like :

```
echo $res->rateInfo->@rateChange;
```

It showing the syntax error in php and when I showing like without @

```
echo $res->rateInfo->rateChange;
```

It not showing the value. Whats wrong with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure but try `$res->rateInfo->{@rateChange}`

Comment: @tradyblix : Thanks...but it is not working

Comment: i know i wasn't sure but was close, @xdazz got it right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `echo $res->rateInfo->{'@rateChange'};`, note you need to quote it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `echo $res->rateInfo->{@rateChange}`;